# Cyclic Dependency in Angular 4 while Opening one modal component from another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my app, I want to open a modal popup for user to upload a file. So I used below code for it (Used angular material to open the popup):

Actual service call happens after I upload document and if uploaded wrong document then service respond with error message.

What I want to achieve is ***If user select incorrect document I want to show another popup (Error Modal popup)***.

However when I import dialog.service.ts in uploaddoc.component.ts gives me below error

> Can't resolve all parameters for UploaddocComponent

also throws warning in console saying :

> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src\app\dialog.service.ts ->
>   src\app\uploaddoc\uploaddoc.component.ts ->
>   src\app\dialog-service.service.ts
>
> WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
>   src\app\uploaddoc\uploaddoc.component.ts ->
>   src\app\dialog.service.ts ->
>   src\app\uploaddoc\uploaddoc.component.ts

Note : UploaddocComponent and ErrorModalComponents are both added in entryComponents array in app.module.ts as both are dynamic components.

Below is my code (and reproduced in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ocymlk?file=app%2Fuploaddoc%2Fuploaddoc.component.ts))

Main Component(to open upload popup ):

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" (click)="openUpload()">Open Upload Popup</button>
```

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material';
import { DialogService } from './dialog.service';
import { ErrorModalComponent } from './error-modal/error-modal.component';
import { UploaddocComponent } from './uploaddoc/uploaddoc.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,private dialogsService: DialogService){

  }
  public openUpload(){
    this.dialogsService.openUploadDialog(UploaddocComponent);
  }
}
```

My **dialog.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ErrorModalComponent } from './error-modal/error-modal.component';
import { UploaddocComponent } from './uploaddoc/uploaddoc.component';
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
@Injectable()
export class DialogService {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) { }
  public infoPopup(): Observable<boolean> {

        let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ErrorModalComponent>;

        dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ErrorModalComponent);
        dialogRef.componentInstance.data = "error";
        return dialogRef.afterClosed();
    }

     public openUploadDialog(data: Object): Observable<boolean> {

        let dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UploaddocComponent>;

        dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UploaddocComponent);
        dialogRef.componentInstance.data = data;
        return dialogRef.afterClosed();
    }

}
```

**upload.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { DialogService } from '../dialog.service';
import { ErrorModalComponent } from '../error-modal/error-modal.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploaddoc',
  templateUrl: './uploaddoc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploaddoc.component.css']
})
export class UploaddocComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialogService: DialogService) { }
  data: any;
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public uploadDoc() {
    //in this method actual service call happens and check if correct document is uploaded or not.
    // Service side sends error if wrong document is uploaded.
    // If wrong doc is uploaded then I want to display Error component here
    // I will simulate service call here with delay and will open ErrorModal

    of(['some data']).pipe(
      delay(2000)
    ).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      // suppose error occured here then I want to open error modal So I added `dialog.service.ts` here in this component

      this.dialogService.infoPopup();
    })
  }
}
```

**upload.component.html**

```
<p>
Upload popup works

<button type="button" (click)="uploadDoc()">Do upload</button>
</p>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Components } from './materialComponents';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { DialogService } from './dialog.service';
import { UploaddocComponent } from './uploaddoc/uploaddoc.component';
import { ErrorModalComponent } from './error-modal/error-modal.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ...Components,BrowserAnimationsModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent, UploaddocComponent, ErrorModalComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [UploaddocComponent, ErrorModalComponent],
  providers: [DialogService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am not sure How should I handle circular dependency.

I may not have understood ngModule completely but guessing; Not able to inject service in components added in `entryComponents` array in app.module.ts.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I had a similar problem to this and I'm afraid I came to the same conclusion that you did, regarding injecting services into entry components. The workaround for my case was to avoid using the service in the dialog (it wasn't essential, just a nice-to-have). Did you find any better solutions?

Comment: @eraph ..i got one solution to manually inject dependecies in your entry component

Comment: using `Injector` ..import it from `@angular/core` and get your service instance in constructor using its .get method like `this.dialogsService = this.injector.get(DialogsService);`

Comment: Sweet! I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Well...it does removed my error...but warnings are still there ..that can be turned off in angularcli.json...guess I should post it as answer though...not sure tbh..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried below approach:

Modified uploaddoc.component.ts to :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { DialogService } from '../dialog.service';
import { ErrorModalComponent } from '../error-modal/error-modal.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-uploaddoc',
  templateUrl: './uploaddoc.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./uploaddoc.component.css']
})
export class UploaddocComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    this.dialogsService = this.injector.get(DialogsService);
  }
  data: any;
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  public uploadDoc() {

    of(['some data']).pipe(
      delay(2000)
    ).subscribe((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
      // suppose error occured here then I want to open error modal So I added `dialog.service.ts` here in this component

      this.dialogService.infoPopup();
    })
  }
}
```

I have used `injector` from `@angular/core` to explicitly get the service instance and no more error now.
however I can still see warnings. To remove warning I have added following in .angular-cli.json

```
 "defaults": {
    ....
    "build": {
      "showCircularDependencies": false
    }
  }
```